# Ramda chain usage

Tags: ramda.js

From the [documentation](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain):

```
var duplicate = n => [n, n];
R.chain(duplicate, [1, 2, 3]); //=> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
R.chain(R.append, R.head)([1, 2, 3]); //=> [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

The first example is very straight forward, it applies duplicate() to every element in the array and concatenates the result. But I am having trouble understanding the second example. How exactly is it mapping R.append + R.head over the array? Can someone please provide a step by step explanation for the second example ?

I am familiar with compose and currying.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The second example is showing how `R.chain` can be used things other than arrays, such as functions (or anything implementing the Fantasy Land [chain](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain) spec).

If the concept of mapping and then concatenating an array is familiar to you, you can think of mapping a function over another function as plain function composition. The concatenating part will require further explanation.

`R.chain` declares its signature as:

```
Chain m => (a → m b) → m a → m b
```

For arrays, we can swap the `m` with `[]` to get:

```
(a → [b]) → [a] → [b]
```

For functions that receive some argument `r`, it becomes:

```
(a → r → b) → (r → a) → (r → b)
```

So with only the knowledge of those types available, the only way to produce the final `r → b` function is to do the following:

- Pass the received argument `r` to the second function to produce an `a`
- Apply both the new `a` and the original `r` to the first function to produce the resulting `b`

Or in code:

```
// specialised to functions
const chain = (firstFn, secondFn) =>
  x => firstFn(secondFn(x), x)
```

Swapping in the functions from the example, you can see it becomes:

```
x => R.append(R.head(x), x)
```

If you are familiar with [`R.converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) then this is effectively:

```
R.converge(firstFn, [secondFn, R.identity])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it makes a lot more sense to me now.

Comment: Best explanation I've seen of this yet!

Comment: To be honest I still don't get it. Is it that the R.chain function does one thing for arrays and another thing for functions? Are they two functions merged into one? Can the form:


const chain = (firstFn, secondFn) =>
  x => firstFn(secondFn(x), x)


also be made to make sense for the array case? In that case which function would secondFn be?

Comment: @taz0k `R.chain` does behave differently depending on the type of the second argument. For arrays it effectively behaves like `chain = (fn, list) => R.unnest(R.map(fn, list))`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation.

Comment: The `chain` implementation should really be: `const chain = (firstFn,secondFn) =>  x => firstFn(secondFn(x))(x)` because the `firstFn` is curried. That the uncurried version works, is mere coincidence of Ramda's implementation of `append`.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev: yes, that's correct.  When working with Ramda, it's often easy to ignore these concerns.  Perhaps there's too much magic in Ramda's currying, but it does make for a convenient API most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to first look at the abstract version of the `R.chain` for functions and to distinguish between functions `m: r -> a` treated as monads and functions `f: a -> r -> b` treated as Kleisli arrows, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787799/1614973).

Then `R.chain` is defined as:

```
// (a -> r -> b, r -> a) -> r -> b
R.chain = (f, m) => x => f(m(x))(x)
```

This can be useful, when `x` is some kind of configuration parameter, the same for both `f` and `m`. Then `a = m(x)` is the value returned by `m` for that parameter, and `g = f(_)(x)` is the function returned by `f` for the same parameter. Think of `x` as some kind of environment that goes into both `m` and `f`. Then the above definition can be broken down as:

```
R.chain = (f, m) => x => {
    const a = m(x)
        , g = a => f(a)(x)
    return g(a)
}
```

In comparison, the `R.map` for functions corresponds to the case when `f` is independent of that parameter `x`:

```
// (a -> b, r -> a) -> r -> b
R.map = (f, m) => x => f(m(x))
```

which, of course, is the usual function composition from the outside.

Another conceptual approach to define `chain` (aka `bind` in Haskell) is to apply `map` (aka `fmap`) followed by `flatten` (aka `join`).

```
R.chain = (f, m) => {
    // m1: r -> r -> b
    const m1 = R.map(f, m)
    // flattening to fm1: r -> b
    const fm1 = x => m1(x)(x)
    return fm1
}
```

Now for `m = x => R.head(x)` and `f = a => x => R.append(a)(x)`, `R.chain(f, m)` is equivalent to putting the parameter `x` into both `f` and `m` and composing the results:

```
x => R.append(R.head(x))(x)
```

which gives the expected result.

**Warning.** Note that the `R.append` function here must be curried as it represents the Kleisli arrow `a -> r -> b`. Incidentally, `Ramda` provides the same named function also as uncurried, but it is the curried one used here. To see this, let us get our custom uncurried `R.append`:

```
const appendCustom = (a, b) => R.append(a, b)
```

Then note how Ramda's REPL throws an error and gives unexpected result:

```
// Define our own uncurried append
const appendCustom = (a, b) => R.append(a, b)
R.chain(appendCustom, R.head)([1, 2]);
// => t(...) is not a function
```

http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.25.0#?%2F%2F%20Define%20our%20own%20uncurried%20append%0Aconst%20appendCustom%20%3D%20%28a%2C%20b%29%20%3D%3E%20R.append%28a%2C%20b%29%0AR.chain%28appendCustom%2C%20R.head%29%28%5B1%2C%202%5D%29%3B%0A

What really happens here, `appendCustom` is executed in its curried form: `appendCustom(a)(b)`, with the second call is delegated to some internal function returning the error.

Comment: It would be nicer on SO to use a snippet rather than a link to the REPL.  It took me a while of answering questions after snippets were introduced to realize that, but it's definitely more helpful to the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
let R = require('ramda')

// using vanillajs
let append = (arr1) => (arr2) => arr2.concat(arr1)
let double = (arr1) => arr1.map( x => 2*x )

let chain = (f, g) => arr => {
   let yarr = g(arr)
   return f(yarr)(arr)
}

console.log(chain(
   append,
   double
)([10, 15, 20]))

//using Ramda
console.log(R.chain(append, double)([10, 15, 20]))
```

Comment: `append` is not `concat`, see the last example from http://ramdajs.com/docs/#append : `R.append(['tests'], ['write', 'more']); //=> ['write', 'more', ['tests']]`

Answer (score -1):

`chain` is (approximately) defined as (for functions): `(fn, monad) => x => fn(monad(x))(x)`

Therefore, we can transform `R.chain(R.append, R.head)([1, 2, 3]);` like so:

```
R.chain(R.append, R.head)([1, 2, 3]);

R.append(R.head([1, 2, 3]), [1, 2, 3]); // This is the important step

R.append(1, [1, 2, 3]);

[1, 2, 3, 1];
```

[The actual source:](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.25.0/source/chain.js)

```
var chain = _curry2(_dispatchable(['fantasy-land/chain', 'chain'], _xchain, function chain(fn, monad) {
  if (typeof monad === 'function') {
    return function(x) { return fn(monad(x))(x); };
  }
  return _makeFlat(false)(map(fn, monad));
}));
```

The important part of that is this:

```
function chain(fn, monad) {
  if (typeof monad === 'function') {
    return function(x) { return fn(monad(x))(x); };
  }
  return _makeFlat(false)(map(fn, monad));
}
```

According to [the comment in the code](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.25.0/source/internal/_makeFlat.js#L4), "`_makeFlat` is a helper function that returns a one-level or fully recursive function based on the flag passed in."

`_makeFlat(false)` seems to be equivalent to `unnest` and `_makeFlat(true)` seems to be equivalent to `flatten`.

Comment: `monad(x)` makes no sense, unless it is a function

Comment: It is, I clarified in my answer.

Comment: This working code from `ramda` is not self-contained, it is impossible to understand without knowing all the stuff used, simply copying which without explanation is not very helpful.