# Function composition using Ramda

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, pointfree

I have a 2 functions and 1 variable which when combined take the form

```
const value = f(g(x))(x)
```

That is, `f(g(x))` returns a function taking `x` again. I don't like this redundancy and it's preventing me from declaring my function pointfree.

What Ramda function do I need to transform this into R.something(f, g)(x)?

Here's a working example, testable in http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1,

```
const triple = x => x * 3
const conc = x => y => x + " & " + y

const x = 10

conc(triple(x))(x)

// I'm looking for R.something(conc, triple)(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`R.chain`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain)

```
const something = chain(conc, triple)
```

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda repl](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20triple%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2A%203%0Aconst%20conc%20%3D%20x%20%3D%3E%20y%20%3D%3E%20x%20%2B%20%22%20%26%20%22%20%2B%20y%0A%0Aconst%20x%20%3D%2010%0A%0Aconst%20something%20%3D%20chain%28conc%2C%20triple%29%0A%0Asomething%28x%29)**.

Comment: for those scratching their heads why `chain` works in this specific case, you’ll need to read about the Function monad – nice answer, Scott

Comment: @naomik: There's also an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787799/1243641) from scott-christoper explaining this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function result which does

```js
const triple = x => x * 3
const conc = x => y => x + " & " + y

let result = (a, b) => e => a(b(e))(e)

const x = 10

console.log(conc(triple(x))(x));

// I'm looking for R.something(conc, triple)(x)

console.log(result(conc, triple)(x));
```