# How do I refactor this composed function with Ramda.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, ramda.js

i am writing a small utility using `ramda` and `data.task` that reads image files out of a directory and outputs their size. I got it working like so:

```
const getImagePath = assetsPath => item => `${assetsPath}${item}`

function readImages(path) {
  return new Task(function(reject, resolve) {
    fs.readdir(path, (err, images) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve(images)
    })
  })
}

const withPath = path => task => {
  return task.map(function(images) {
    return images.map(getImagePath(path))
  })
}

function getSize(task) {
  return task.map(function(images) {
    return images.map(sizeOf)
  })
}

const getImageSize = dirPath => compose(getSize, withPath(dirPath), readImages)
```

The problem is with the `withPath` function that adds the correct image path to the image file name but forces my api to pass in the directoryName twice: once for reading the files and second time for reading the path. This means I have to call the `getImageSize` function like so:

```
const portfolioPath = `${__dirname}/assets/`

getImageSize(portfolioPath)(portfolioPath).fork(
  function(error) {
    throw error
  },
  function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
)
```

Is there any way to pass the `dirname` as a parameter only once? I want the api to work like this:

```
getImageSize(portfolioPath).fork(
  function(error) {
    throw error
  },
  function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
)
```

Comment: I'm on my mobile now so can't really test, but you might check out how [`chain`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) works on functions :  `chain(f, g)(x) => f(g(x), x) `.

Comment: Hey @ScottSauyet - was hoping to get your attention. I solved the problem but I still want to understand how I would use chain in this situation. Isn't `chain` just `flatmap` in Ramda?

How would that apply here?

Comment: I was thinking you might be able to switch `withPath` to `task => path => ...` and then compose `getSize` with `chain(withPath, readImages)`.  As for how `chain` works on functions, Scott Christopher provided an [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787799/1243641).

Comment: Ok. I am gonna try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be building paths manually like that

One of Node's better APIs is the [Path module](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) – I would recommend that your `readImages` wrapper is made a generic `readdir` wrapper, and instead resolve an Array of [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)'d file paths

```
const readdir = dir =>
  new Task ((reject, resolve) =>
    fs.readdir (dir, (err, files) =>
      err
        ? reject (err)
        : resolve (files.map (f => path.resolve (dir, f)))


const getImagesSizes = dir =>
  readdir (dir) .map (R.map (sizeOf))
```

Wrapping the Node continuation-passing style APIs just to return a `Task` gets to be a bother, doesn't it?

```
const taskify = f => (...args) =>
  Task ((reject, resolve) =>
    f (...args, (err, x) =>
      err ? reject (err) : resolve (x)))

const readdir = (dir, ...args) =>
  taskify (fs.readdir) (dir, ...args)
    .map (R.map (f => path.resolve (dir, f)))

const getImagesSizes = dir =>
  readdir (dir) .map (R.map (sizeOf))
```

You should probably also take care to file out file paths that are *directories* – unless your `sizeOf` implementation handles that

Comment: i think it's common for most beginning functional programmers to see all problems as a `comp`osition problems – don't worry; that will change over time

Comment: But what you have shown is also a composition pattern isn't it? Could you expand more on your critique? I am a relative beginner at FP and have been learning FP mainly as a series of functional compositions.

Comment: Amit, thank you for highlighting an ambiguity – I intended to differentiate *"[function] composition"* and the *`compose`* function itself – It is valid for you to view all compound functions as the compositions of smaller functions, but remember not all function compositions are written with `compose` function – So yes, `readdir` is a *composition* but in this case, the `compose` function doesn't help us express that composition any better – Most beginners will go "I need a composition", reach for the `compose` function, then wonder why their final program feels awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by passing the `Task` resolution a single object like so:

```
function readImages(path) {
  return new Task(function(reject, resolve) {
    fs.readdir(path, (err, images) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      else resolve({ images, path })
    })
  })
}

const withPath = task => {
  return task.map(function({ images, path }) {
    return images.map(getImagePath(path))
  })
}
```

...and then destructing it out of the task payload and now my compose function looks like this:

```
module.exports = (function getImageSize(dirPath) {
  return compose(getSize, withPath, readImages)
})()
```

And my api call looks like this:

```
getImageSize(portfolioPath).fork(
  function(error) {
    throw error
  },
  function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
)
```