# difference between chain() and map() in ramda.js

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

What is the difference between `chain()` (from `ramda` package) and `map()` in Javascript?

In both functions the programmer inputs an object and some lambda/function and gets a certain calculation of it. Thanks.

Comment: `chain` isn't a native JS method on the Array.prototype

Comment: `chain` is from ramda

Comment: Can you edit your question with that knowledge and tag so that people aren't confused, please?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I understand. But except for it, are these functions equivalent?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) no. "chain maps a function over a list and concatenates the results. chain is also known as flatMap in some libraries"

Comment: Read about [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Look deeper into which calculation happens with the object and the lambda.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Abstract Types

`chain` and `map` each operate on an abstract type.  `map` operates on any **[Functor](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#functor)**.  This is any item with a `map` function that obeys certain laws.  `chain` operates on a **[Chain](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain)** element.  Similarly, this is something with a lawful `chain` function, as well as having lawful `apply` and `map` functions.

Ramda provides `map` and `chain` functions that will work with types fulfilling these contracts.  It also supplies implementation for certain built-in types (functions, arrays, and objects for `map` and functions and arrays for `chain`.)

To see how they differ, it's simple enough to compare their signatures:

```
// map   :: Functor f => (a → b)   → f a → f b
// chain :: Chain   m => (a → m b) → m a → m b
```

You can think about it like this: the function supplied to `map` takes an item of type A and returns one of type B.  `map` accepts that function and a container holding type A and returns a container holding type B.  The function supplied to `chain` by contrast takes an item of type A and returns a *container* holding type B.  `chain` accepts that function and a container holding type A, returning a container holding type B.

You can think about it as though `chain` unwraps one level of containers compared to `map`.

### Some Examples

For example, let's say we had a function `factors`, which returns the factors of an integer (`factors(14) //=> [1, 2, 7, 14]`, for instance.)  Here is how `map`  and `chain` would work on a list of numbers:

```
map(factors, [12, 15])   //=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12], [1, 3, 5, 15]]
chain(factors, [12, 15]) //=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12, 1, 3, 5, 15]
```

Or if we had a `Maybe` type used to simplify null-handling with the subtypes `Just` to signify a value and `Nothing` to signify some null in the computation.  We might write a safe square root function such as

```
const sqrt = (n) => n > 0 ? Just(Math.sqrt(n)) : Nothing()
```

Then we see these differences between `map` and `chain`.

```
map(sqrt, Just(25)) //=> Just(Just(5))
chain(sqrt, Just(25)) //=> Just(5)

map(sqrt, Just(-25)) //=> Just(Nothing)
chain(sqrt, Just(-25)) //=> Nothing
```

And finally, for functions, for reasons described in **[another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787799/1243641)**,

```
map(f, g)   //~> x => f(g(x));
chain(f, g) //~> x => f(g(x))(x);
```

### Summary

You can see from their signatures, that there is some relationship between `map` and `chain`, but they are distinct functions, used for very different purposes.  `chain` is related to what is sometimes called `flatMap`, as it flattens out (one level) of the sort of result created by `map`.

But the best way to think about them is to look at the signatures and the laws tied to these functions.

Answer (score 2):

**Update August 2019**

Agree entirely with Scott's answer ;)  Wished to add a simple example by way of comparison. Let’s say you had a collection of friends who all had several favourite foods. We can use chain (aka flatMap) to create an array of all the foods you should serve at your next party.

```
import * as R from "ramda";

const friends = [
  {
    name: "Jill",
    favoriteFoods: ["pizza", "hummus"]
  },
  {
    name: "Bob",
    favoriteFoods: ["ice cream"]
  },
  {
    name: "Alice",
    favoriteFoods: ["chicken wings", "salmon"]
  }
];

let favouriteFoods = R.map(friend => friend.favoriteFoods);

console.log(favouriteFoods(friends));
//-> [ [ 'pizza', 'hummus' ], [ 'ice cream' ], [ 'chicken wings', 'salmon' ] ]



favouriteFoods = R.chain(friend => friend.favoriteFoods);

console.log(favouriteFoods(friends));
//-> [ 'pizza', 'hummus', 'ice cream', 'chicken wings', 'salmon' ]
```

A common pattern is to combine a flattening function with a mapping one. You could explicitly map then flatten in 2 separate steps. Chain, however, does both for you.