# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyArray<{}>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, ramda.js

Full Typescript error:

> Argument of type '(c: IAsset) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(n: IAsset) => ReadonlyArray<{}>'.
>     Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyArray<{}>'.

My `calculatePercentage` function:

```
// Add coin's percentage of portfolio
export const calculatePercentage = (portfolio: IAsset[], coin: IAsset) => {
  if (coin) {
    portfolio.push(coin);
  }

  const addValue = (c: IAsset) => c.value;
  const values = R.chain(addValue, portfolio);
  const total = values.reduce((acc: number, val: number) => acc + val);

  const updatedPortfolio = portfolio.map((c) => {
    c.percentage = round((c.value / total) * 100);
    return c;
  });

  return updatedPortfolio;
};
```

With `addValue` I'm taking in a type of `IAsset` and just returning it's value (`number`);

In [R.chain](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain)`(addValue, portfolio)`, the `addValue` function is then used on each item in `portfolio` which is of type `IAsset`.

**My interface:**

```
export interface IAsset {
  currency: string;
  exchange: string;
  marketCap: number;
  name: string;
  percentage: number;
  price: number;
  position: number;
  value: number;
}
```

[image]

Thoughts on how to correct set the type here?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49863741/1243641) might shed some light on the difference between chain and map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with Ramda, but reading the docs, it seems like this would work:

```
const addValue = (c: IAsset) => [c.value];
const values = R.chain(addValue, portfolio);
```

But it appears that what you really meant to use was [`map`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map)

```
const addValue = (c: IAsset) => c.value;
const values = R.map(addValue, portfolio);
```

Which equivalent to the built-in [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
const addValue = (c: IAsset) => c.value;
const values = portfolio.map(addValue);
```

But you can also use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the total without the intermediate step to get `values`:

```
const total = portfolio.reduce((acc: number, { value }: IAsset) => acc + value, 0);
```

I suppose the Ramda-flavored version of this would be something along the lines of this:

```
var getValue = (c: IAsset) => c.value;
var adder = (a: number, b: number) => a + b;
R.reduce(adder, 0)(R.map(getValue)(portfolio));
```

Comment: Thanks! 100% appreciate this! I guess I over complicated the function due to my love of Ramda lol